# Android - CertificateFactory.generateCertificates(Inputstream) return 0

Tags: java, android, ssl-certificate, ca

I am trying to load a .pem file into Inputstream and then trying to generateCertificates. But, I am getting 0 certificates. Whereas my .pem file has various certifcates. Below is the code I am using:

```
try{
    AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();
    InputStream in = am.open("cacerts.pem");
    if(in!=null){
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Collection<? extends Certificate> certificates = certificateFactory.generateCertificates(in);
        if (certificates.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected non-empty set of trusted certificates");
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and my cacerts.pem is something like this:

```
# This is a bundle of X.509 certificates of public Certificate
# Authorities.  It was generated from the Mozilla root CA list.
#
# Source: mozilla/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt
#
# Generated from certdata.txt RCS revision 1.39
#
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number:
            02:ad:66:7e:4e:45:fe:5e:57:6f:3c:98:19:5e:dd:c0
        Signature Algorithm: md2WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=RSA Data Security, Inc., OU=Secure Server Certification Authority
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov  9 00:00:00 1994 GMT
            Not After : Jan  7 23:59:59 2010 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=RSA Data Security, Inc., OU=Secure Server Certification Authority
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (1000 bit)
                Modulus (1000 bit):
                    00:92:ce:7a:c1:ae:83:3e:5a:aa:89:83:57:ac:25:
                    01:76:0c:ad:ae:8e:2c:37:ce:eb:35:78:64:54:03:
                    e5:84:40:51:c9:bf:8f:08:e2:8a:82:08:d2:16:86:
                    37:55:e9:b1:21:02:ad:76:68:81:9a:05:a2:4b:c9:
                    4b:25:66:22:56:6c:88:07:8f:f7:81:59:6d:84:07:
                    65:70:13:71:76:3e:9b:77:4c:e3:50:89:56:98:48:
                    b9:1d:a7:29:1a:13:2e:4a:11:59:9c:1e:15:d5:49:
                    54:2c:73:3a:69:82:b1:97:39:9c:6d:70:67:48:e5:
                    dd:2d:d6:c8:1e:7b
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: md2WithRSAEncryption
        65:dd:7e:e1:b2:ec:b0:e2:3a:e0:ec:71:46:9a:19:11:b8:d3:
        c7:a0:b4:03:40:26:02:3e:09:9c:e1:12:b3:d1:5a:f6:37:a5:
        b7:61:03:b6:5b:16:69:3b:c6:44:08:0c:88:53:0c:6b:97:49:
        c7:3e:35:dc:6c:b9:bb:aa:df:5c:bb:3a:2f:93:60:b6:a9:4b:
        4d:f2:20:f7:cd:5f:7f:64:7b:8e:dc:00:5c:d7:fa:77:ca:39:
        16:59:6f:0e:ea:d3:b5:83:7f:4d:4d:42:56:76:b4:c9:5f:04:
        f8:38:f8:eb:d2:5f:75:5f:cd:7b:fc:e5:8e:80:7c:fc:50
MD5 Fingerprint=74:7B:82:03:43:F0:00:9E:6B:B3:EC:47:BF:85:A5:93
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----


Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 419 (0x1a3)
        Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=GTE Corporation, CN=GTE CyberTrust Root
        Validity
            Not Before: Feb 23 23:01:00 1996 GMT
            Not After : Feb 23 23:59:00 2006 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=GTE Corporation, CN=GTE CyberTrust Root
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus (1024 bit):
                    00:b8:e6:4f:ba:db:98:7c:71:7c:af:44:b7:d3:0f:
                    46:d9:64:e5:93:c1:42:8e:c7:ba:49:8d:35:2d:7a:
                    e7:8b:bd:e5:05:31:59:c6:b1:2f:0a:0c:fb:9f:a7:
                    3f:a2:09:66:84:56:1e:37:29:1b:87:e9:7e:0c:ca:
                    9a:9f:a5:7f:f5:15:94:a3:d5:a2:46:82:d8:68:4c:
                    d1:37:15:06:68:af:bd:f8:b0:b3:f0:29:f5:95:5a:
                    09:16:61:77:0a:22:25:d4:4f:45:aa:c7:bd:e5:96:
                    df:f9:d4:a8:8e:42:cc:24:c0:1e:91:27:4a:b5:6d:
                    06:80:63:39:c4:a2:5e:38:03
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
        12:b3:75:c6:5f:1d:e1:61:55:80:00:d4:81:4b:7b:31:0f:23:
        63:e7:3d:f3:03:f9:f4:36:a8:bb:d9:e3:a5:97:4d:ea:2b:29:
        e0:d6:6a:73:81:e6:c0:89:a3:d3:f1:e0:a5:a5:22:37:9a:63:
        c2:48:20:b4:db:72:e3:c8:f6:d9:7c:be:b1:af:53:da:14:b4:
        21:b8:d6:d5:96:e3:fe:4e:0c:59:62:b6:9a:4a:f9:42:dd:8c:
        6f:81:a9:71:ff:f4:0a:72:6d:6d:44:0e:9d:f3:74:74:a8:d5:
        34:49:e9:5e:9e:e9:b4:7a:e1:e5:5a:1f:84:30:9c:d3:9f:a5:
        25:d8
MD5 Fingerprint=C4:D7:F0:B2:A3:C5:7D:61:67:F0:04:CD:43:D3:BA:58
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

As seen clearly, I have 2 certificates but I don't know why is `generateCertificates()` returning 0?

Is there a different way to read certificate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Same issue on android 6.0. But certificates generating properly on 4.2.2